# VoiceOVer and Bootstrap menu modal

Tags: ios, bootstrap-modal, voiceover

I have a menu button that opens a drop down menu modal. One is how I prevent VoiceOver from reading right off the menu and second when I double tap outside the menu to close focus goes to the parent page and not back to the menu button.

Comment: What do you mean by "reading right off the menu" this is confusing.  Your other question is easy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I await clarification on the first part.  As for the second, you want to post a notification, with the element to be focused.

```
UIAccessibilityPostNotification(UIAccessibilityLayoutChangedNotification, viewToBeFocused);
```